# How can I plot a discontinuous ceiling function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, floor, ceil

Here is the code I am using to plot graph of ceiling function in python.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
y = np.ceil(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('ceil(x)')
plt.ylabel('graph of ceil (x)')
plt.title('graph of ceil (x)')
plt.show()
```

I tried, `np.arange` to consider float values between two integers, but though can't plot that correct graph which is disconnected and shows jump in graph as we draw in maths.

Comment: If you need a different plot type, [don't call plot()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html), which is for drawing data in the assumption that it's a continuous function. You almost certainly want `step()`.

Comment: `y`, is just an array of numbrs.  It isn't a function.  `plt` just draws a line between all the `x,y` pairs.  It isn't, in a mathematical function sense, a contiguous, or discontinuous, function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
y = np.ceil(x)

plt.xlabel('ceil(x)')
plt.ylabel('graph of ceil (x)')
plt.title('graph of ceil (x)')

for i in range(int(np.min(y)), int(np.max(y))+1):
    plt.plot(x[(y>i-1) & (y<=i)], y[(y>i-1) & (y<=i)], 'b-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `y` you'll see it's just numbers, `1.0` etc.  `plot.plt(x,y)` shows a continuous stairstep plot.  Zoomed in enough you'll see that the verticals aren't exactly that; they show the change in `y` from `1.0` to `2.0`, with in one small step in `x`.

Look at every 100th value of `x`.

```
In [13]: x[::100]
Out[13]:
array([-5.0000000e+00, -4.0000000e+00, -3.0000000e+00, -2.0000000e+00,
       -1.0000000e+00, -1.0658141e-13,  1.0000000e+00,  2.0000000e+00,
        3.0000000e+00,  4.0000000e+00])
```

Looking a `ceil` at those points, and following:

```
In [15]: np.ceil(x[::100])
Out[15]: array([-5., -4., -3., -2., -1., -0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
In [16]: np.ceil(x[1::100])
Out[16]: array([-4., -3., -2., -1., -0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

We could change `y` at each of those jumps to `np.nan`.

```
In [17]: y[::100]=np.nan
```

Then the `plt(x,y)` will skip the `nan` values,  and show just the flats without the near-vertical riser.

[image: dash continuous, blue with nan]

red dash in the connected `y`, blue is the disconnected with `nan` values.

The other answer does a separate `plot` for each level.

A comment suggested `stair`, but I haven't worked out the calling details.

In any case, getting disconnected plot requires special handling of the plotting.  It isn't enough to just create the `x,y` arrays.